# How to transpose an Image buffer in Halide?

Tags: c++, halide

I want to transpose a Halide::Buffer.Is there a way to do it?

I have tried transpose() in Halide. But it shows error.

```
    Halide::Func B;
    Halide::Var x, y, c; 
    B(x, y, c)= 0.0f;
    B(0,0,c)=  1.0f; B(1,0,c)= 0.0f; B(2,0,c)= 0.0f; 
    B(0,1,c)=  1.0f; B(1,1,c)= 2.0f; B(2,1,c)= 0.0f; 
    B(0,2,c)=  1.0f; B(1,2,c)= 2.0f; B(2,2,c)= 3.0f;

    Halide::Buffer<float> B_mat = B.realize(6, 6, 1);

    Halide::Buffer<float> C_mat = B_mat.transposed(0,1);
```

error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘Halide::Buffer’ requested
     Halide::Buffer C_mat = B_mat.transpose(0,1);

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there is a mismatch between the code you posted and your errer message.
Your error message states that you have used `transpose(0, 1)`, this doesn't return a `Halide::Buffer<float>`:

```
void transpose(int d1, int d2)
```

You should take a alook at the [documentation of transpose and transposed](https://halide-lang.org/docs/class_halide_1_1_runtime_1_1_buffer.html#a82b28d656d63704c6cc14adc3939d69f) and use

```
Buffer<T, D> transposed(int d1, int d2)
```

instead.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your reply! The last line was "Halide::Buffer<float> C_mat = B_mat.transpose(0,1);"  You are right. I understand "B_mat.transpose(0,1)" returns void. But, wondering how to correct it. Reading the Halide document, it is not clear to me. Would you please explain how to use "Buffer<T, D> transposed(int d1, int d2)" in correct way! That would be a great help!

Comment: Buffer<float>C_mat = B_mat.transposed(0,1);                                                 gives error message:                                                                                       ‘class Halide::Buffer<float>’ has no member named ‘transposed’; did you mean ‘transpose’?
     Buffer<float>C_mat = B_mat.transposed(0,1);

Comment: Try using Halide::Runtime::Buffer instead Halide::Buffer

Comment: I have fihured it out. it will be:                                                                                       "B_mat.transpose(0,1);" then the index of B_mat will be reversed!